# How to provide jar parameters to Julieops for confluent kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, devops, confluent-cloud

I am trying to use julieops to create kafka infrastructure on Confluent

https://github.com/kafka-ops/julie

I am trying to run the julie-ops.jar file but don't know how to fill out the parameters in the screenshot (no documentation).

How to provide the indicated parameters in the screenshot below.

For example, where can I find a sample file for “clientConfig” parameter, how can I know the accepted structure of the file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few examples [here](https://github.com/kafka-ops/julie/blob/master/src/main/conf/topology-builder.properties) but the documentation is clearly lacking a comprehensive list.

This page lists some [important configuration values](https://julieops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-values.html).